# flexWrap not working for <Text> element in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

Here is my sceanario

```
var FlexWrap = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return(<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <Image source={{uri:profileImage}}
             style={{width:100,height:100}}>
      </Image>
      <View style={{marginLeft:5}}>
        <Text style={{marginTop:5,
          marginBottom:5,
          flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
          This sample text
          should be wrap
          wrap wrap ....
        </Text>
        <Text style={{marginTop:5,
          marginBottom:5,
          flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
          This sample text
          should be wrap
          wrap wrap ....
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>)
  }
})
```

Here

> 'This sample text should be wrap wrap wrap ....'

is in single
line, but in my scenario based on the window width automatically the
text should be wrap.
Here i am using `flexWrap: 'wrap'`  to wrap the text, but what is the correct way to wrap the text?

> Please find the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Are you on iOS or Android? I tested you code on iOS and it seems to be working.

Comment: I am working for both IOS and Android.In IOS  simulator the text  wrap is not done.Please find the attached screenshot above

Comment: When i am using flexDirction:'row' to the parent View then that text wrap is not working otherwise without flexDirection:'row'  it's working.But in my scenario flexDirection:'row' is necessary and at the time text wrap also compulsory how to acheieve this plaese help me

Comment: I got the solution ,when using with flexDirection:'row' the solution is the wrapped Text  Hold View set to flex:1,i updated the code above.

Answer (score 26):

set `flex: 1` to wrapper view of text

```js
var FlexWrap = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return(<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <Image source={{uri:profileImage}}
             style={{width:100,height:100}}>
      </Image>
      <View style={{marginLeft:5,flex:1}}>//<=== ADDED flex:1
        <Text style={{marginTop:5,
          marginBottom:5
        }}>
          This sample text
          should be wrap
          wrap wrap ....
        </Text>
        <Text style={{marginTop:5,
          marginBottom:5
        }}>
          This sample text
          should be wrap
          wrap wrap ....
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>)
  }
})
```

[Help link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/901)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Note: based on my testing, only `flexShrink: 1` is required to make this work, at least for my use case: https://codesandbox.io/embed/7wlorrx3p1

Answer (score 2):

I think if you specify the flex property in the stylesheet for the text it will wrap.

```
<Text style={{marginTop:5, marginBottom:5, flexWrap:'wrap', **flex: 5,** }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var FlexWrap = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return(<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <Image source={{uri:profileImage}}
             style={{width:100,height:100}}>
      </Image>
      <View style={{marginLeft:5,flex:1,flexDirection:'column', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>// Changes here
        <Text style={{marginTop:5,
          marginBottom:5
        }}>
          This sample text
          should be wrap
          wrap wrap ....
        </Text>
        <Text style={{marginTop:5,
          marginBottom:5
        }}>
          This sample text
          should be wrap
          wrap wrap ....
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>)
  }
})
```

You will have your desired result if you change your flex direction and wrap it

Answer (score 0):

simply you could do sth like below:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Text>Your Text</Text>
</View>
```